# Inserting xml nodes containing namespaces outside of document node

Tags: c#, xml

I'm creating an XML document in C# that is similar to the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>2015-05-17-track.kml</name>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I can create everything except for the kml node.  How do I add this to the XmlDocument?

This is the code I'm using, without the kml node.

```
doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Document");
doc.AppendChild(root);

//form the declaration
XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null );
doc.InsertBefore(declaration, root);

XmlNode nameNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "name", "");
nameNode.InnerText = name;
root.AppendChild(nameNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Append child to DocumentElement.

```
XmlNode nameNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "name", "");
nameNode.InnerText = name;
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(nameNode );
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question.  I can add the name no problem.  How do I add the 'kml' node above the document node? (see sample xml)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was misled by the 'Document' node.  It's been a while and I thought the XmlDocument.DocumentElement always had a tag of 'Document'.  Wrong!
Here is the revised code

```
    doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement( "kml" );
    root.SetAttribute( "xmlns", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" );
    root.SetAttribute( "xmlns:gx", "http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" );
    root.SetAttribute( "xmlns:kml", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" );
    root.SetAttribute( "xmlns:atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" );
    doc.AppendChild( root );

    //form the declaration
    XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration( "1.0", "UTF-8", null );
    doc.InsertBefore( declaration, root );

    //Document node
    XmlElement documentNode = doc.CreateElement( "Document" );
    root.AppendChild( documentNode );

    //add the name node
    XmlNode nameNode = doc.CreateNode( XmlNodeType.Element, "name", "" );
    nameNode.InnerText = name;
    documentNode.AppendChild( nameNode );
```